# How to remove a view from superview, without reloading?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, subview, superview

I have a game, and i want to remove an obstacle. But when i do this, the view is completely refreshing itself. But I want the other subviews to stay, where they where.

To remove this subview I use:

```
obstacles.removeFromSuperview()
```

Then it disappears on the screen, but after that all other subviews are set to their original Position..

is there another method, or do i have to save the positions and after reloading set it back again? wouldn't that look bad and buggy?

Btw, when i added my view to subview, it was a let. don't know if its important..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the other subviews move it means that their position depends on the view you removed. Working with auto layout take into account that `removeFromSuperview` removes any constraints that refer to the view you are removing (or to its children).

Comment: aha. and how could i solve this problem? by placing my movingView somewhere else before removing the other??

Comment: if you are working with auto layout you could create constraints with lower priority between the remaining views and other elements of your view controller (not the view you remove), so that they become active when the view is removed and constrain the remaining views to the desired position

Comment: thanks for all your effort, but i simply just hide it until the end and remove it from my dictionary, so i won't touch it.. and finally when leaving the VC it gets removed..   again: thanks a LOT!!